# DllImport, Char*& and StringBuilder C/C#

Tags: c#, dllimport, stringbuilder

I have a problem, I tried to look at almost all the poster solutions, unsuccessful to find a suitable one.

The question is easy, Want to have a return string from unmanaged C code in my managed C#.
The c function is:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int process_batch (char *&result);
```

and in C# I imported the DLL:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr process_batch(StringBuilder result);
```

I run, but the return value in my StringBuilder is a 7-8 character string of non-sense! (I think the memory address)

I tried adding ref before the StringBuilder, this time I get the correct return value in StringBuilder but I get AccessViolationException :
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

So I need your help to fix this.

Just one more thing, I use malloc in c for allocating the memory to the char* variable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to do that, pass the parameter as a `ref IntPtr`, then call [Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx), or similar.

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr process_batch(ref IntPtr result);
```

Note that, since you're allocating the string with `malloc` in C, the .NET program will have to keep track of the returned pointer so that it can pass it back to you to be deallocated. Otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

If you were to pass a `ref StringBuilder`, you wouldn't be able to deallocate the memory that was allocated by the C program.

Also, as somebody commented in another post, you need to set the calling convention:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the following code successfully:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClassName", ExactSpelling = false,
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int _GetClassName(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder lpClassName,
            int nMaxCount);

public static string GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd)
{
   StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(MAXTITLE);
   int titleLength = _GetClassName(hWnd, title, title.Capacity + 1);
   title.Length = titleLength;

   return title.ToString();
}
```

I'd advise for a more specific declaration of the imported method via the `DllImportAttribute`. Try the `CharSet = CharSet.Auto` bit for instance

I know that this is not exactly related to your original problem as this makes use of the Windows API, but maybe it is of help nonetheless.

Comment: I also would declare the calling convention.  Most of the problems I have seen dealing with p/Invoke deal with the calling convention.

Comment: @Ramhound: Excellent point! In this case it should be `Cdecl`- right?