# Failed to cast result of Marshal.GetActiveObject for COM interop wrapper

Tags: c#, com-interop, idl

I'm struggling to work out how to access a COM interface provided by a C++ application and use it from a C# .NET application.

I try to access my COM object (which is provided by a running process) from my C# app like this:

```
object obj = Marshal.GetActiveObject("MyLibrary.Application");
MyLibrary.IMainApp app = (MyLibrary.IMainApp)obj;
```

The value of `obj` is non-null, but when I try to cast it I get `System.InvalidCastException`.

I tried implementing a custom wrapper and also linked against a DLL produced by `TlbImp.exe`.  Both produced the same exception.

There seems to be a lot of documentation regarding interop, but it's not making sense to me -- mostly because I'm not COM-savvy (I am stuck maintaining code that someone else developed), and am entering the scary world of C#, .NET and WPF by diving headlong into it.

Here's what I have on the C++ end....

**IDL File**

Actually, the extension is `.odl`.  I don't know if that's a different thing.  Note that I've replaced the GUIDs with placeholders like `GUID-1`, `GUID-2` *etc*...

```
import "oaidl.idl";

[ uuid(GUID-1), helpstring("My Type Library"), version(1.1) ]
library MyLibrary
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");

    //  Primary dispatch interface for CMainApp

    [ uuid(GUID-2) ]
    dispinterface IMainApp
    {
    properties:
        [id(1)] BOOL Mode;

    methods:
        [id(2)] void Quit();
        [id(3)] void LogEventMessage(BSTR szMessageType, BSTR szMessage);
        [id(4)] BOOL GetNoteDetails(BSTR szQualifiedName, BSTR* lpbstrOperator, DATE* lpdtDate);
    };

    //  Class information for CMainApp
    [ uuid(GUID-3) ]
    coclass Application
    {
        [default] dispinterface IMainApp;
    };
};
```

**Example Usage**

When another C++ application wants to call a function (*eg* `Quit`), they do this:

```
CLSID       clsid;
HRESULT     hr;
LPUNKNOWN   lpUnk;
LPDISPATCH  lpDisp;
BOOL        bReturn = FALSE;

// Get Class ID
if (CLSIDFromProgID( OLESTR("MyLibrary.Application"), &clsid ) == S_OK )
{
    // Get Active Object from ROT
    if ( ( hr = GetActiveObject( clsid, NULL, &lpUnk ) ) == S_OK )
    {
        hr = lpUnk->QueryInterface( IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID*)&lpDisp );
        lpUnk->Release();
        if ( hr == S_OK )
        {
            CMainApp oMainApp;
            oMainApp.AttachDispatch( lpDisp );

            TRY
            {
                oMainApp.Quit();
                bReturn = TRUE;
            }
            CATCH( CException, e )
            {
                bReturn = FALSE;
            }
            END_CATCH
        }
    }
}
```

The class `CMainApp` seems to have been auto-generated by the IDL compiler.  That file is compiled into the project that wants to use it, and basically does a whole lot of `InvokeHelper` calls.  I'm happy enough to accept this is just the way it works, and I hope that C# is less convoluted.

**Attempt to wrap in C#**

I followed an MSDN guide on COM interop in C#.  It suggested I could use `TlbImp.exe` but that threw up enough warnings to put me off.  Besides, I don't want to distribute another DLL.  So I took the other approach of writing a wrapper.

This is what I wrote:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    // Declare MainApp COM coclass
    [ComImport, Guid("GUID-3")]
    class MainApp
    {
    }

    [Guid("GUID-2"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    interface IMainApp
    {
        public void Quit();

        public void LogEventMessage(
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string szMessageType,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string szMessage );

        public bool GetNoteDetails(
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string szQualifiedName,
            [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string lpbstrOperator );
            out DateTime lpdtDate );
    }
}
```

---

Can someone gimme a hand to understand this?  Perhaps point out a totally obvious stupid mistake that I've made? =)

Comment: Check this out, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16209219/2095843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample C++ code is using *late-binding* through IDispatch.  Which is the correct way to do it, your COM server doesn't support early binding.  You can tell from the IDL, it uses *dispinterface* instead of *interface*.

The equivalent way in C# is by using the C# `dynamic` keyword.  Like this:

```
dynamic obj = Marshal.GetActiveObject("MyLibrary.Application");
obj.Quit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks. I can control every item in Excel by declaring the ExcelWorkBook as dynamic.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook AWB;
        Excel._Worksheet ASH;
        dynamic ExcelWorkbook;
        try
        {
            ExcelWorkbook = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            AWB = ExcelWorkbook.ActiveWorkBook;
            String naam = AWB.Name;
             ASH = AWB.ActiveSheet;
            oXL = ExcelWorkbook.Application();
            object theValue = oXL.get_Range("A1", "A1").Value2;
            ASH.Cells[1, 1] = "First Name";
            ASH.Cells[1, 2] = "second Name";
            ASH.Cells[1, 3] = "Third Name";
            ASH.get_Range("A1", "D1").Font.Bold = true;
        }
        catch { }
        String tekst="test";
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 9 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.